# Neatest/most idiomatic way to rewrite this If in C#

Tags: c#, refactoring, code-snippets, code-readability, conditional-statements

I have this `if-else` statement which does what I want. What it's doing is pretty straightforward as you should be able to tell.

```
if (width != null && height != null)
{
    if (top != null && left != null)
    {
        ret.type = VMLDimensionType.full;
    }
    else
    {
        ret.type = VMLDimensionType.size;
    }
}
else
{
    if (top != null && left != null)
    {
        ret.type = VMLDimensionType.positon;
    }
    else
    {
        ret.type = VMLDimensionType.unset;
    }
}
```

The `enum` being referred to is:

```
private enum VMLDimensionType
{
    unset = 0,
    full = 1,
    size = 2,
    position = 3
}
```

It's so straightforward I'm sure there's a much more terse and more readable way to express this.

NB If it wasn't for the ridiculous 'one-brace per line' rule that VS imposes by default I probably wouldn't be so bothered. Eg in VB I could lose about 10 lines from this code block! (any thoughts on that as an aside?)

Comment: If I didn't miscount it, the VB.NET version would be 7 lines shorter, a version without braces 12 lines.

Comment: Can you post the `VMLDimensionType` enum? It might be simpler if it were a Flags enum.

Comment: @Ani Updated with enum definition

Comment: @El: well, just change the defaults. VS luckily allows this. Having each brace on an extra line like this really *is* a waste and doesn’t contribute to readability (IMHO).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to make `VMLDimensionType` a `Flags` enumeration:

```
[Flags]
enum VMLDimensionType
{
    Unset = 0,
    Size = 1,
    Position = 1 << 1,
    Full = Size | Position
}
```

And then:

```
ret.Type = VMLDimensionType.Unset;

if(width != null && height != null)
    ret.Type |= VMLDimensionType.Size;

if (top != null && left != null)
    ret.Type |= VMLDimensionType.Position;
```

Comment: Hmm, I may have to change my accepted answer :) This makes more sense as the enum is reflecting the actual logic...

Comment: @cibacity Full is implicit when Size and Position have both been set. That's the beauty of it. Doing the logical `OR` makes this happen.

Comment: @El Ronnoco: Dammit I need some sleep - of course it does, I'm being dense - doh!

Comment: Why do you write `1 << 1` and not simply `2`?

Comment: @Oliver: You're right, I could do that. This is how I normally write flags enums. To me, it clarifies that we are setting the second bit (1 shifted left by a bit).

Comment: @Ani: Shouldn't you then be consequent and also write `1 << 0` instead of `1` ;-)

Comment: @Oliver: I suppose, but to me, that's the "base" case.

Answer (score 9):

```
bool hasPosition = (top != null && left != null);
bool hasSize = (width != null && height != null);

if (hasSize)
{
    ret.type = hasPosition ? VMLDimensionType.full : VMLDimensionType.size;
}
else
{
    ret.type = hasPosition ? VMLDimensionType.positon : VMLDimensionType.unset;
}
```

Comment: Coding with least number of lines isnt the best IMHO. Code with less number of lines with a clear readability makes it the best. This one fits the bill.

Comment: +1 I like it, nice and readable actually. Kind of like reading from a chart. Similar to others but still..

Comment: Apologies, I've changed my accepted answer to Ani's as I like the way they've made the enum reflect the logic of what is going on.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
bool hasSize = width != null && height != null;
bool hasPosition = top != null && left != null;

if (hasSize && hasPosition)
{
    ret.type = VMLDimensionType.full;
}
else if (hasSize && !hasPosition)
{
    ret.type = VMLDimensionType.size;
}
else if (!hasSize && hasPosition)
{
    ret.type = VMLDimensionType.positon;
}
else
{
    ret.type = VMLDimensionType.unset;
}
```

Comment: +1 I quite like the readability that this solution gives. It's still quite big, but that may just be me getting used to all these braces :)

Comment: @El Ronnoco On single line statements you CAN remove the braces - I would recommend keeping them though, as it makes merging changes in source control easier, and gives you a definitive groupings that your eye can run over.

Comment: @Will yes, when I first started with C# I used to leave out the braces for single line code blocks. Then I had to make some of them two line code-blocks....

Answer (score 2):

I would like to extract GetDimensionType() method.
And make it not so small, but more readable and self-descriptive.

```
private VMLDimensionType GetDimensionType()
{
    bool hasSize = width != null && height != null;
    bool hasPosition = top != null && left != null;

    if (hasSize && hasPosition)
        return VMLDimensionType.full;

    if (hasSize)
        return VMLDimensionType.size;

    if (hasPosition)
        return VMLDimensionType.positon;

    return VMLDimensionType.unset;
}
```

Usage:

```
ret.type = GetDimensionType();
```

Comment: Where are `top,left,width` and `height` coming from? Or are they being accessed as members?

Comment: Yes, I suppose this is a members of some object.
Anyway, if they are not, you can pass them as parameters.

Comment: +1 for mid-function returns.  Note how nicely they turn the `else if`s of all the other solutions into simpler `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
if(width != null && height != null)
    ret.type = top != null && left != null ? VMLDimensionType.full : VMLDimensionType.size;
else
    ret.type = top != null && left != null ? VMLDimensionType.positon : VMLDimensionType.unset;
```

Comment: Didnt see Chibacity's comment before i posted :(

Comment: Yes, but not the neatest. His is better imo

Comment: @1 Ahh a nice bit of humility!